# Update new column using If sum condition on existing fields

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, sumifs

```
unique_id    site      status      Final status
HMEX093     MEX025    Accepted      Incomplete
HMEX093    HMEX056    Accepted      Incomplete
HMEX093     LTY0014   Pending       Incomplete
```

I want an update query to update Final status column depending if query on status.
every unique_id has multiple sites with different status.
I want to update final status column with if sum of condition. 
for eg. unique_id HMEX093 has 3 sites with different sites. I want to check status of these sites,if sum(status='Accepted') of site >= 3 final status column should be updated with value Approved.
If there is atleast one pending status to corresponding sites of unique_id, final status shoul be updated as Incomplete as shown above.
please help.
I tried with Case when statement, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Now that I realize the question was about MySQL, not Excel, I think something like the following query would work:

```
update
  Sites
inner join
(
  select
    s1.unique_id,
    if(s2.accepted_sites = count(*),'Accepted','Incomplete') as final_status
  from
    Sites s1
  left outer join
  (
    select
      unique_id,
      count(*) as accepted_sites
    from
      Sites
    where
      status = 'Accepted'
    group by
      unique_id
  ) as s2 on s2.unique_id = s1.unique_id
  group by
    s1.unique_id
) s on s.unique_id = Sites.unique_id
set
  Sites.final_status = s.final_status
```

What this query does:

- The inner `select` statement counts the number of sites that are accepted for each unique ID.
- The outer `select` statement compares the total number of sites for each unique ID and compares it with the number of accepted sites. If the counts are equal, the final status is "Accepted", otherwise, it is "Incomplete".
- The `update` statement sets the final_status to the results of the outer `select` statement. (I wasn't able to test the update part, but hopefully it's at least close.)

---

**Original answer for doing this in Excel**

If your table is located at A1,

Try entering this **array forumula*** into cell D2 and copying is down to the last row of your table:

`=IF(SUM(IF((A$2:A$10=A2)*(C$2:C$10="Accepted"),1,0))=COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2),"Accepted","Incomplete")`

*Array formulas allows you to crunch numbers on entire columns of data at once, rather than just one row at a time. To enter an array formula, you need to type or paste in the formula then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you've done this successfully, the formula should gain curly braces around it, like this:

`{=IF(SUM(IF((A$2:A$10=A2)*(C$2:C$10="Accepted"),1,0))=COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2),"Accepted","Incomplete")}`

What this formula does:

- The outer `IF` statement puts "Accepted" if the condition is true, otherwise, it puts "Incomplete"
- The `COUNTIF` statement counts the number of IDs in the entire `unique_id` column that match the `unique_id` of the current row.
- The `SUM` and inner `IF` statements add up the number of rows where the `unique_id` matches the `unique_id` of the current row **and** the status is "Accepted". (Note that, with an array formula, `*` means `and`.)

So, overall, the formula checks if the number times an ID is accepted is the same as the number of rows with than ID.

Here is my test table:

```
unique_id   site        status      final_status
HMEX093     MEX025      Accepted    Incomplete
HMEX093     HMEX056     Accepted    Incomplete
HMEX093     LTY0014     Pending     Incomplete
HMEX094     MEX025      Accepted    Accepted
HMEX094     HMEX056     Accepted    Accepted
HMEX094     LTY0014     Accepted    Accepted
HMEX095     MEX025      Pending     Incomplete
HMEX095     HMEX056     Pending     Incomplete
HMEX095     LTY0014     Pending     Incomplete
```

Comment: Hi devuxer,
Thank you so much for the information, but i am dealing with mysql query.
 and not the excel sheet .
any advice ??

Comment: I just changed the first tag of your question from Excel to MySQL Looking at the edit history, someone added the Excel tag to your question, but that was misleading.

Comment: @Priyanshu, Just updated my answer with a MySQL query. I wasn't able to test whether the update query works, but the select query inside the update query does seem to work, so hopefully that will get you started.